# how to update object using index in react state?

Tags: reactjs

suppose i am having an array of like

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "John" , selected: true}
  { id: 2, name: "Jim" , selected: false }
  { id: 3, name: "James" , selected: false }
]
```

I am having function which get id and on  the basis of that id I want to change the `selected` property of object to true and other  `selected` property  object to false

here is my function what i have tried but its throwing error

```
const handleOnClick = (id) => {
     const temps = state.findIndex((sub) => sub.id === id)
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [prevState[temps].selected]: !prevState[temps].selected
        }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `.map()` to iterate everything.  You shouldn't change values within the array without recreating the tree down to the changed object.  See below example.

Below you will:

1. `map` over every element
2. Spread their current values
3. Overwrite the `selected` depending on if the `id` is the newly "selected" `id`

I also supplied an additional function to update using the index of the item in the array instead of by `id` since your title is "how to update object using index in react state?", although your question also mentions changing by `id`.  I would say go by `id` if you have the choice, array indices can change.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: "John" , selected: true},
    { id: 2, name: "Jim" , selected: false },
    { id: 3, name: "James" , selected: false }
  ]);

  // This takes the ID of the item
  const handleOnClick = (id) => {
    const newState = state.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        selected: item.id === id
      };
    });
    
    setState(newState);
  };
  
  // This takes the index of the item in the array
  const handleOnClickByIndex = (indexToSelect) => {
    const newState = state.map((item, idx) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        selected: indexToSelect === idx
      };
    });
    
    setState(newState);
  };
        
  return (
    <div>
      {state.map((item, mapIndex) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <div>
            <span>{item.name} is selected: {item.selected ? "yes" : "no"}</span>
            {/* This will update by ID*/}
            <button onClick={() => handleOnClick(item.id)}>Select using ID</button>
            {/* This will update by the index of the array (supplied by map) */}
            <button onClick={() => handleOnClickByIndex(mapIndex)}>Select using index</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```